# How to copy the semester[20] string under the structure, and count and print it in my output

Tags: c

I don't want to hard code fall19 and spring19 into the output. I want whatever the user input into the array semester[20] under the structure be counted and inputted into the printf. (The inputs are in a text file named enrollment.txt)

Here is the text file for enrollment.txt

```
10 c1 fall19 80
10 c2 fall19 85
10 c3 fall19 95
40 c2 fall19 65
2 c1 fall19 70
40 c4 fall19 95
40 c5 fall19 85
2  c2 fall19 50
4 c4  spring19 95
4 c5 spring19 89
13 c1 spring19 99
13 c2 spring19 75
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include<string.h>

struct Enrollment { 
int stud_id;
char course_id[5];
char semester[20];
float score;
}; // end struct Enrollment
struct Enrollment enroll[50];         

    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      if (strcmp(enroll[i].semester, "fall19") == 0) {
        count1++;
      } else if (strcmp(enroll[i].semester, "spring19") == 0) {
        count2++;
      }
    }
    printf("\n%s %d", "fall19", count1);
    printf("\n%s %d", "spring19", count2);
    printf("\n------------------");
    printf("\n==================");
    printf("\n------------------");

  }
}

 }
 return 0;
  }
```

Example output:

```
  fall19 8
  spring19 4
  summer19 0
```

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? Where is the code that reads the enrolement.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, i do not see your function, i think you forget `main`, right ? if it's typo, you can see my idea below:

Firstly, you have to store data from `enrollment.txt` into array `enroll[50];`.
For this task, you can get line by line of text file using `fgets` or `getline` function. For exmaple:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("enrollment.txt", "r");
if(!fp) {//handle error};
char line[256];
int i = 0;
while(line, sizeof(line), fp) {
    // using sscanf to read data from line to array
}
fclos(fp);
```

For reading the data from line, you can use `sscanf`:

```
int err = sscanf("%d %s %s %f\n", &enroll[i].stud_id, enroll[i].course_id, enroll[i].semester, &enroll[i].score);
if(err != 4) {//handle the error}
i++;
```

Then you can use `for` loop from `0` to `i` to increase `count1` and `count2` as your code.